# How to log document changes on Windows Server 2008 with AD?

Tags: logging, windows-server-2008, auditing, change-tracking

Ok so we have a team of developers working on files stored on a Windows Server 2008 R2, usually txt files. These developers log in remotely using their own username/password from the Active Directory on the server. They all have rwx access to a specific share on the server.

Recently, there have been many issues regarding mysterious document changes that “no one” made. Unfortunately, we cannot view who was the last user who modified the specific file.

Any ideas of how can we log the changes made on a file including the user who did the modifications?

They login to the server from a shared drive on their computers. (network drive)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keywords here would be file auditing, check the following: 
http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Auditing_Windows_Server_2008_File_and_Folder_Access

Comment: that seems to be what I am looking for. Thanks a lot!